# All docker containers suddenly stopped at once. How to debug docker itself?

Tags: docker

It happened twice now that all my containers stopped all of a sudden.

I would suspect, my VPS test server restarted somehow. Might be RAM issues maybe.

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            987         572          67          59         347         175
Swap:          1975         551        1424
```

I can not seem to find a similar question on here. Most of them are concerned with how to stop containers.

Furthermore, what would be the best implementation to get notified, when a container stops?

**Edit:**
All processes had this status:

```
Exited (255)
```

Comment: Did you use some monitoring?

Comment: Not yet. Any suggestions, Jan?

Comment: I will try out prometheus with grafana. Looks promising.

Comment: The 255 is the exit code of the process you were running. Try to understand the possible causes of that.

Comment: I think a possible cause could be the lack of RAM on my server, but I don't know where to check for past logs of Docker.